# Stop removing selected value when selecting options using select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a combo box that can be selected multiple times. Here is the HTML.

```
<select multiple>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

JS Code

```
$('select').select2();
$('select').change(function(){
    $("select").val([]); // clear selected value
});
```

I want to be able to select more than once on the same option. For example, if I select 1, then I should be able to select 1 again. But, when I select an option in select2, the selected value is removed from the list. I have tried to empty the selected value right after I select a value, but selected value still get removed.

For example, I select an option with value 1. This makes an option with value 1 remove from the list, leaving only 2,3,4,5 in the list. When I select an option with value 2, this option is removed and an option with value 1 is back. This makes the option list become 1,3,4,5.

I want all of the options show up when the option is selected. But, I can't get around this. I have tried every solution possible, but none of it works.

Comment: I think using checkboxes would be much better for your issue.

Comment: what is this useful for? what are you trying to do by confusing the user?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the `val([])` contains all the possible selections from 1 to 5. So according to this you should try to include your `$("select").val([])` into a for loop. For example:

```
$('select').select2();
$('select').change(function(){
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
   $("select").val([i]);
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

I have found a solution on your problem but I don't know if it works for you without knowledge on your project.

Here is a `select` tag that when you click on an option or more options, then the clicked one/ones is/are removed from the `select` tag list:

HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect" size="4">
  <option onclick="myFunction()">1</option>
  <option onclick="myFunction()">2</option>
  <option onclick="myFunction()">3</option>
  <option onclick="myFunction()">4</option>
  <option onclick="myFunction()">5</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
      x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
    }
</script>
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: `val([])` contains zero array. I want to remove any selected value after I select a value.

Comment: @david So did the above worked for you? You should close the question or ask for further info.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see your edit answer. anyway, i have already solved my problem. thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: You should provide to us your solution though. That's why you are seeking help in the community

Answer (score 0):

There are several open issues on Select2 repo (see: [#1002](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1002), [#1674](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1674), [#2672](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2672)) but this feature has never been implemented.

A workaround is to re-append the option selected:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var configParamsObj = {
    templateResult: formatResultData,
  };
  $("#sel").select2(configParamsObj);
});

$("#sel").on("select2:select", function(e) {
  $("#sel").append('<option value="' + e.params.data.text + '">' + e.params.data.text + '</option>');
});

$("#sel").on("select2:unselect", function(e) {
  e.params.data.element.remove();
});

function formatResultData(data) {
  if (!data.id) return data.text;
  if (data.element.selected) return
  return data.text;
};
```

```css
select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css"> 

Multiple select w/duplicates
<div>
  <select id="sel" multiple>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

P.S.: offside effect is that options are appended at the end of dropdown.